# cannot find directory inside NX project which is bundled with webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack, path, directory-structure, monorepo

I try to read directories using this node function fs.readdirSync(__dirname).

However, after the build I can't see the same folder structure, and the previous function throws an error: `ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'src/db/models'`
In the dist folder of the app, there are only assets folder, main.js and main.js.map.

So how can I change the configuration in order to find the folders correctly?
I use [NX](https://nx.dev/tutorials/integrated-repo-tutorial) to create the app and webpack as bundler.

I added  `config.node = { __dirname: true }` to the webpack's composePlugins to be able to use --dirname.